# Updating react-native packages still gives 'deprecated ViewPropTypes' error

Tags: react-native, package, version, deprecated

I am working on upgrading a react-native application from v0.60 to v0.70.
I have updated all the packages to the latest but after building the app successfully, I am getting a white screen when the app is launching on the emulator. In the terminal it is giving the error -
"Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'., js engine: hermes"

I tried to see if there are any ViewPropTypes being used in my node_modules and I updated all the third-party packages using them. Still, I am getting the same error.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCrGk.png)

> Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'., js engine: hermes